# Solr cannot reindex due to strange query being produced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am writing a rails applications that utilize solr for full text search

In development mode, I used the sunpost solr gem which is really handy. I used the sqlite3 database in development and everything went smooth.

Now is the time to move to production server and I installed the solr-tomcat package and moved to my production database which is Mysql. I moved the conf files of solr from my application folder to /usr/share/solr/conf

Suddenly, I cannot reindex, and solr returned this

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production sunspot:solr:reindex
[#                                 ] [  50/7312] [  0.68%] [00:00] [00:41] [ 175.82/s]rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'barangs.' in 'where clause': SELECT  `barangs`.* FROM `barangs`  WHERE (`barangs`.`` >= 0) ORDER BY `barangs`.`` ASC LIMIT 50
```

Intrigued, I tried to reindex with the development database, all is well and can be reindexed. This behavior left me baffled

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. It was due to me dropping and restoring tables recklessly and it loses some relationships definitions.

Hence the "missing" column on table 'barangs'.'**MISSING**' solr can't find the specified column.

For others who are facing the problem, I recommend inspecting the relationship between models first